# 'function' object has no attribute 'MY_SETTING'

Tags: python, django

In my `views.py` I have

```
from django.conf import settings

  def site_view(request):
    ...
    if some_var == settings.MY_SETTING:
  ...
```

The value `MY_SETTING` is defined in `settings.py`. However I get the following error when I try and load the view:

```
Exception Type:    AttributeError
Exception Value:   'function' object has no attribute 'MY_SETTING'
```

What's going on?

Comment: Did you call a function in views.py `settings`?

Comment: Do you have a function called `settings()`?

Comment: if you print `settings` what is the output?

Comment: @NPE Yes, rubber ducked this question quite hard.

Comment: Just happened to me. This is why we shouldn't code late at night...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

How about importing settings like:

```
from django.conf import settings as conf_settings
```

then:

```
if some_var == conf_settings.MY_SETTING:
```

Comment: The reason this may work for you is because in this view you also have a settings() function. Django is complaining because it thinks you're referencing your defined settings() function, rather than the settings file you're trying to import. See NPE's comment.